# How to set SetKeepAlivePeriod on a *tls.Conn

Tags: go, ssl, tcp

I want to increase the keep alive period of my TCP connection for both HTTP and HTTPS requests.

For HTTP requests this can be done like this:

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "io"
    "log"
    "net"
    "net/http"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    server := &http.Server{Addr: ":8080", Handler: http.HandlerFunc(func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        io.WriteString(w, "Hello, World!")
    })}

    server.ConnState = func(conn net.Conn, state http.ConnState) {
        if state == http.StateNew {
            if err := conn.(*net.TCPConn).SetKeepAlivePeriod(1000 * time.Second); err != nil {
                fmt.Println("Could not set keep alive period", err)
            } else {
                fmt.Println("update keep alive period")
            }
        }
    }

    log.Fatal(server.ListenAndServe())
}
```

For HTTPS requests this cannot be done via `server.ConnState` because the `net.Conn` that will be passed inside the function is a `*tls.Conn`. This connection does not expose a function like `SetKeepAlivePeriod` or gives access to the underlying `*net.TCPConn`.

```golang
func main() {
    server := &http.Server{Addr: ":8080", Handler: http.HandlerFunc(func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        io.WriteString(w, "Hello, World!")
    })}

    server.ConnState = func(conn net.Conn, state http.ConnState) {
        if state == http.StateNew {
            tlsConn := conn.(*tls.Conn)
            // how to set SetKeepAlivePeriod
        }
    }

    log.Fatal(server.ListenAndServeTLS("../example.crt", "../example.key"))
}
```

How can I set the keep alive period for tls connections?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are (at least) two ways to do it:

### Use a [net.ListenConfig](https://golang.org/pkg/net/#ListenConfig):

The `net.ListenConfig` object has a `KeepAlive time.Duration` field. When non-zero, this will be used to set the keep-alive on accepted connections (eg: [for TCP on posix](https://golang.org/src/net/tcpsock_posix.go?#L138)).

You can pass the listener to `ServeTLS`:

```golang
server := &http.Server{...}

lc := net.ListenConfig{KeepAlive: 1000 * time.Second}
ln, err := lc.Listen(context.Background(), "tcp", ":8080")
if err != nil {
  panic(err)
}
defer ln.Close()

log.Fatal(server.ServeTLS(ln, "../example.crt", "../example.key"))
```

As mentioned, accepted TCP connections will automatically have keep-alive enabled and the period set to the specified value.

### Use a [tls.Config](https://golang.org/pkg/crypto/tls/#Config) callback:

You can access the `net.Conn` underlying the `tls.Conn` by setting the [tls.Config](https://golang.org/pkg/crypto/tls/#Config) `GetConfigForClient` or `GetCertificate` callback.

It does not matter which one you're using as long as you return `nil` to make the TLS code fall back to the default behavior. The important part is to get access to the [tls.ClientHelloInfo](https://golang.org/pkg/crypto/tls/#ClientHelloInfo) which has a `.Conn` field pointing to the underlying connection. This will the `net.TCPConn`.

```golang
setTCPKeepAlive := func(clientHello *tls.ClientHelloInfo) (*tls.Config, error) {
  // Check that the underlying connection really is TCP.
  if tcpConn, ok := clientHello.Conn.(*net.TCPConn); ok {
    if err := tcpConn.SetKeepAlivePeriod(1000 * time.Second); err != nil {
      fmt.Println("Could not set keep alive period", err)
    } else {
      fmt.Println("update keep alive period")
    }
  } else {
    fmt.Println("TLS over non-TCP connection")
  }

  // Make sure to return nil, nil to let the caller fall back on the default behavior.
  return nil, nil
}

tlsConfig := &tls.Config{
    ...
    GetConfigForClient: setTCPKeepAlive,
    ...
}

server := &http.Server{
    Addr:      ":8080",
    TLSConfig: tlsConfig,
}

server.ListenAndServeTLS("../example.crt", "../example.key")
```

Comment: Setting `KeepAlive` on `net.ListenConfig` seems like the best solution, no type assertions needed and it just works. Thanks!

Comment: I fleshed out the `net.ListenConfig` method and listed it first since it's lot simpler.